# RMI client gets null return value

Tags: java, rmi

I have written a RMI server app with following API in it-

IDbInfo getDatabaseInfo();

This API returns database info class object, this class inherits from IDbInfo.
Till now everything was going perfectly fine, client app was able to get proper return value from RMI server.

Some days ago we installed RMI server on fresh Debian machine, and client on winodows machine. After that client application always get return value as null. I added logs in RMI server to verify value returned, and found that server does return proper value, but somehow client app receives it as null.

I tried to reproduce this issue by installing RMI server on a Fedora machine and client on windows (in our test environment), but there everything works fine. Issue occurs only on this particular Debian machine.

can anyone point me to possible reason of this problem?

----edit----

following is definition of my return types-

```
public interface IDbInfo extends Serializable {
....
}

public class MysqlDatabaseAccessInfo implements IDbInfo {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a remote method returns null, it is because you coded it that way.

Comment: Indeed, it was a silly bug on server side which was returning null. Side effects of later night programming!